# awk / split to return lines with a certain value in a certain column - create blocks of 100,000

Tags: awk, split, grep

I have a csv file where the third column is a number. Some of the entries don't have a value in this column.

I want to pull 100k blocks from the file, but only entries with a valid value for that column.

I could use split, but how do I make it check that column for a value?

Comment: what did you try? can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat test.txt
1,2,3,get me
4,5,,skip me
6,7,8,get me
9,10,11,stop before me
$ awk -F, '$3!="" && ++i<=2' test.txt
1,2,3,get me
6,7,8,get me
```

Comment: this will drop the records with `0` value as well.  Perhaps not a valid assumption.

Comment: True, true. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to verify whether or not the third field within a record has a value and output its contents if it does, you could try the following:

```
awk -F , '{ if($3 != ""){print $3} }'
```

This could also be written as:

```
awk -F , '$3 != ""{print $3}'
```